# manifest.json no longer being generated on Heroku in Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm deploying a Rails app on Heroku.

My manifest.json file is no longer getting generated on the push to Heroku in my production environment.

Here are some relevant bits from my config file:

`config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.digest = true`

When I deploy, `helper.asset_path('production_vendor.js')` returns a path without an md5 hash and the assets are not found.

I've spent a few hours attempting to find solutions to this and eventually decided to precompile my assets locally then check in my local manifest.json file.

This works but makes my deployment process a bit fragile.

Any ideas why manifest.json may have stopped being generated?